# Native module cannot be null. | React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to run on the iOS simulator but keep receiving this error:

Native module cannot be null.

Image of error:

[image]

Comment: Just open the app into the Xcode and check which library not found.

Comment: There are no libraries missing: https://i.imgur.com/vqBVQQL.png

Answer (score 0):

Did you do in ios directory the Podfile installation ?

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Comment: Yes I did run pod install inside that directory.

Comment: Witch package are you using ? This error is when your package is not properly linked to your project

Comment: Use this package => @react-native-firebase (the documentation is [here](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/)). It's really well explained and all firebase modules are splits so you can import only what you want